# Repository Pattern with mixed Logic

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

My ProductRepository has a method, lets say:

```
GetAllCalculatedProducs(int categoryId) {}
```

This method uses class Calculator to compute many values of the product. It looks just like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllCalculatedProducts(int categoryId)
{
  var items = GetAllProductsByCategoryId(categoryId);

  Calculator c = new Calculator(items);
  c.Calculate();

  Filter f = new Filter(c.Items);
  f.Filter();

  Sorter s = new Sorter(f.Items);
  s.Sort();

  return s.Items;
}
```

Calculator does his work using another repositories.

> [DB] <--> [Repository] <- |Business Logic| ->
>   [Calculator]

I assume that is wrong due to the fact that Repository uses class which belongs to Logic. I even think that this method should be in other place maybe in ProductService? but I'm not sure.

And can Filter and Order be use in repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only add methods to the repository that directly or indirectly work against the database. Your method do not do that, it calls `GetAllProductsByCategoryId` which works with the DB. Hence it should be part of the service instead.

If it had generated an own query and done some filtering and sorting on it, I would have not had any problems with that.

Comment: thanks for the reply so the solution could be like this:  http://pastie.org/1859961, right?

Comment: yes. Although I would use more specific names for `Sorter`, `Filter` and `Calculator`. Maybe `SortOnLastName`, `FilterOutOldEntries`, `CalculateAveragePrice`.